# Moment.subtract.format does not work for UTC offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to subtract one hour, and in this case to get `-08:00`.

```
console.log(moment().format('Z')); // -07:00
```

However when I do the following (I've tried all permutations) it gives me the same result.

```
console.log(moment().subtract( 1 , "hours").format('Z')); // -07:00
```

What is the correct usage here?

Answer (score 2):

`Z` is just going to give you the offset from UTC in your timezone. I'm guessing you're in California or somewhere in PST.

Try this:

```
moment().format('HH') // "20" for me in EST
```

versus

```
moment().subtract( 1 , "hours").format('HH'); // "19" for me in EST
```

This should give you what you're looking for, hopefully.

Comment: I'm trying to get the UTC offset, minus one.

Comment: @AlexKornhauser something like `moment.utc().subtract(1, 'hours').format('HH');`

Comment: See what I have above? It's `-07:00`. Your method would give me `16`